# JQuery post JSON data throwing error, "unquoted Identifier 'Id' at position 0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using Fiddler to monitor the Jquery post I get an error in fiddler.

> unquoted Identifier 'Id' at position 0

What am I missing?

```
  var UserModel =
            {
                Id: "12345",
                Name: "MyName"
            };             
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("MyAction")',
                data: UserModel,
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Seriously!! As a person who has made ~ 36 posts on jQuery, this is not expected of you :(  Dude your JSON is broken!!!! Sorry for this personal comment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot the quotation mark

```
var UserModel =
            {
                "Id": "12345",
                "Name": "MyName"
            };
```